# Using C# class library in apache cordova android app

Tags: javascript, c#, android, cordova

I have winjs windows app that i need to port to android with apache cordova and visual studio 2015. In my app, i'm using c# portable class library to do some calculations and return result in javascript.

I'm simply referencing class library project, and call something like `MyClassLibrary.MyClass().MyMethod()` to get result i need. I tried this in cordova, but can't even find option to reference external project..

On the web i have found that could be done by creating cordova plugins, but can't find any working examples how to do this... Can someone point me how to use my c# class library in cordova app for android?